# Yahoo WebPlayer: Content-type audio/mpeg not supported

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, mp3, yahoo-api

I'm using yahoo web player for playing some files.

It's working fine in Chrome. But in Firefox a error message is showed: **Content-type audio/mpeg not supported**

If I get the file url in mensagem and open in another tab, works fine.

It doesn't work on IE too.

> Works in Firefox 12, but don't works on Firefox 15

The error mensage:

> this.currentEngine is null
>
> Line 82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yahoo WebPlayer depends from Flash Player in Firefox and IE.